# Boolean conditionals with placeholder

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, boolean

super beginner here:

I having trouble figuring out how to correctly use this conditional statement for a placeholder.  For some reason, it only executes one condition after clicking on submit (in this case, always true) whether or not there's a string typed into the placeholder.

This is the code I have so far:

```
function handleObj(task){
    p.textContent = 'My goal is to ' + task.toLowerCase()
    if (typeof p.textContent !== 'string'){
        h.textContent = 'Please type a goal'
        p.textContent = ' '
        submit.disabled = true;
    }
    };
```

TIA

Comment: If you assign a string to the `.textContent` and then check to see if it's a string... yes, it'll always give you a string. Check the `task` instead

Comment: Unfortunately, replacing it with task made no changes.  I also tried removing .textContent on p and it only returned the !== regardless.

Comment: Where do you call `handleObj`?

Comment: I put right here: 



.document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        handleObj(e.target.goal.value)
    })
});

Comment: If the function runs and is targeting the proper element, checking whether `task` is the empty string does sound like it'd be your solution

Comment: Unfortunately, it always return true even when there’s nothing typed into the placeholder when replacing p.textContent with task

Comment: Please edit a MCVE into your question with a live Stack Snippet so others can reproduce the problem too - that way it can be debugged effectively

Comment: Thanks for the help.  The task advice was part of the solution.  I just replace the boolean and just used ‘’ instead.